# Cannot Update google adwords account through API (i.e., UpdateAccount())

Tags: google-ads-api

i'm not able to pro grammatically update the google account using UpdateAccount() method in AccountService . I'm getting exception, when trying to update the address field. can some one let me know . what  is  the updateable fields in AccountInfo class. if possible with the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Both primaryAddress and billingAddress fields of AccountInfo are not updateable.

If you are looking an easy way to programmatically manage AdWords account and you are using .NET platform, you should take a look at GemBox.Ppc [AdWords API for .NET](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/Ppc/Overview.htm).

It greatly simplifies management of AdWords accounts.